# How work with foreign keys in Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, pojo

I'm new to Hibernate. This is my problem. I can do this:

```
package = session.createQuery("from Package").list();
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

But what I really want is this in SQL:

```
select * from package,product where product.nome='television' and package.idProduct = product.id
```

How do I do that?

These are my POJOs:

```
public class Package implements java.io.Serializable {

  private PackageId id;
  private User user;
  private Product product;
  private int quant;
  private char mode;
  private String unit;
  private String description;

public class PackageId implements java.io.Serializable {

  private int id;
  private int idProduct;

public class Product  implements java.io.Serializable {

  private int id;
  private String name;
  private Set packages = new HashSet(0);
```

These POJOs were generated by Netbeans.

Is this configuration right?

http://pastebin.com/gBUdKke0

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any configuration. With Hibernate you can have annotations in a class (OneToMany springs to mind for packages) or an hbm.xml file per dao. Or you're using JPA with named queries using the JPA API with a hibernate implementation.

Comment: Is your questions that you want to know how to perform the given SQL query with Hibernate? You haven't posted any configuration.

Comment: sorry guys there it is http://pastebin.com/gBUdKke0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already working with HQL. With HQL you can select multiple objects not just one or just a set of object fields.

```
select product, package 
from Product product
join product.packages package
where product.name = 'television'
```

See HQL reference for [select](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select) for examples.

Comment: Thank you so much Aleksi, in my case stay this way in the end:
select distinct package from Product product, Package package join package.product where product.name = 'television'  and product.id = package.produto.id